# Restoring 1.6mb sql via file upload (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

phpMyAdmin can successfully restore a 1.6MB dump file with LONGBLOG data. I am trying to replicate this function but my function doesn't seem to work. I receive a segmentation fault error and it seems to never execute any of the backup file's code. (But it does drop tables)

I believe the segfault is when doing the preg_split.

Here is the routine for restoring: (This works great on small files without LONGBLOB DATA)

```
function do_restore()
{
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    if(!$this->Employee->authentication_check($password))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>"failure"));
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $sq=file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
        $tables = $this->db->list_tables();

        foreach ($tables as $table)
        {           
            $this->db->query('drop table '.$table);
        }

        $this->db->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
        $queries = preg_split("/;+(?=([^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'][^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'])*[^'|^\\\']*[^'|^\\\']$)/", $sq); 
        foreach ($queries as $query) 
        {
            if($query) 
            {
                $this->db->query($query);
            } 
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>"success"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add some code to make sure you have valid file contents. You aren't checking to make sure that `$sq` is valid (not empty or null) before it's being used in the call to `preg_split`.

Comment: The file I am sending is a valid SQL file, will be adding validation.

Comment: Sorry. I meant checking for null or empty string.

Comment: That is being added to. I think it is getting a bit off topic though. How do I parse a large file without causing as segmentation fault?

Comment: Sorry. I think I was a little dense when I first read your question. It just now sunk in that you are only running into this issue for really large files. You may need to stream the file in a line at a time until you have a complete query, and then hand that query to the database. I suspect that `preg_split` just can't handle all the data you are giving it, so to work around that, try to give it less to work on at a time.